# How to convert JSON string to Object in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, object

Hello I am a newbie in Swift, I have this link http://api.sabriapps.com/FikraSpace/db.json , I want to convert this JSON to Objects in Swift & there is also a another problem that loading pictures is very slow

Comment: Your question seems to be of a low quality please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Please include [what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your required code :

```
 let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string: "http://api.sabriapps.com/FikraSpace/db.json")!, options: nil, error: nil)

    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
        error: nil) as NSDictionary

    println("Dictionary :  \(jsonResult)")

    var jsonEvents = jsonResult["events"] as NSArray

    println("Array :  \(jsonEvents)")

    var firstObject : NSDictionary = jsonEvents[0] as NSDictionary ;

    println("First Obj :  \(firstObject)")

    var name = firstObject["name"] as NSString

    println("Name :  \(name)")

    var timeStamp = firstObject["timestamp"] as NSString

    println("TimeStamp :  \(timeStamp)")

    var duration = firstObject["name"] as NSString

    println("duration :  \(duration)")

    var description_en = firstObject["description_en"] as NSString

    println("Description :  \(description_en)")

    var location = firstObject["location"] as NSString

    println("Location :  \(location)")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to show it on the collectionview cell ?

Comment: Go through : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9STtYpxIwj4. And please accept my answer, if it helped you.

Comment: Dude, the OP put no effort into his question. He said "how do I parse this JSON in swift" and you wrote him a bunch of code. Don't do that. This is not a "write code for me" site. It's a site to get help solving problems with code you've written, after **putting in an effort**.  Your answer was comprehensive, but gave the OP too much. The OP can now copy/paste your code and not learn anything.

Comment: Note his comment to the other answer: "Can you type the code for me." Translation: "Can you do all my work for me so I can copy/paste it."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSJSONSerialization class as in objective c:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:

the JSONObjectWithData method returns you an NSDictionary or an NSArray which you can parse then

Comment: Can you type the code for me.